# How to overlay one 2D array over another and extract characters?

Tags: java, arrays, overlay, extract

My task is to read in a message and key, then overlay the two before decoding it.
The message.txt file contains random characters in a table NxN. The key.txt contains 'x' and ' ' that once laid over the message would reveal a secret.
The problem with my code is when I try to print out the overlay version, I just get the key again. Is the inner loop of my overlay method wrong or is it something else? My intentions is to overwrite everything in the message.txt file with x's so that what remain/standout are the letters that make up the code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class project1
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int i = 0;
      int j = 0;
      int row = 0;
      String s = "";
      char[][] message = new char [20][20];
      char[][] key = new char [20][20];
      char[][] overlay = new char [20][20];

      message = message(row, i, j, s, message);
      key = key(row, i, j, s, key);
      overlay = overlay(row, i, j, key, message, overlay);


      print2DArray(row, i, j, s, message, key, overlay);

   }

   public static char[][] message(int row, int i, int j, String s, char[][] message)
   {
      File f;
      Scanner inFile = null;
      try {
         f = new File("secret_message.txt" );
         inFile = new Scanner( f );
      } catch ( IOException e ) {
         System.out.println( "Error opening : " + "secret_message.txt");
      }   

      while(inFile.hasNextLine()) //determine n X n
      {
         String nxn = inFile.nextLine();
         row++ ;
      }

      try {
         f = new File("secret_message.txt" );
         inFile = new Scanner( f );
      } catch ( IOException e ) {
         System.out.println( "Error opening : " + "secret_message.txt");
      }

      for(i = 0; i < row; i++ ) //row; storing message
      {
         s = inFile.nextLine();
         for(j = 0; j < row; j++) //column
         {
            message[i][j]= s.charAt(j);
         }
      }
      inFile.close();

      return message;
   }

   public static char[][] key(int row, int i, int j, String s, char[][] key)
   {
      File f;
      Scanner inFile = null;
      try {
         f = new File("key.txt" );
         inFile = new Scanner( f );
      } catch ( IOException e ) {
         System.out.println( "Error opening : " + "key.txt");
      }   

      while(inFile.hasNextLine()) //determine n X n
      {
         String nxn = inFile.nextLine();
         row++ ;
      }

      try {
         f = new File("key.txt" );
         inFile = new Scanner( f );
      } catch ( IOException e ) {
         System.out.println( "Error opening : " + "key.txt");
      }

      for(i = 0; i < row; i++ ) //row; storing key
      {
         s = inFile.nextLine();
         for(j = 0; j < row; j++) //column
         {
            key[i][j]= s.charAt(j);
         }
      }
      inFile.close();  
      return key;
   }

   public static char[][] overlay(int row, int i, int j, char[][] message, char[][] key, char[][] overlay)
   {
      for(i = 0; i < row; i++)
         for(j = 0; j < row; j++)
         {
            if(key[i][j] == 'x')
               message[i][j] = key[i][j];

         }
      return message;

   }   

   /*public static String decodeMessage( )
   {
      for (j = overlay[0].length-1; j >= 0; j--)
         for(i = overlay[0].length-1; i >= 0; i--)
         {
            =message[i][j]
         }

   }

   */

   public static void print2DArray(int row, int i, int j, String s, char[][] message, char[][] key, char[][] overlay)
   {
      for(i = 0; i< message.length; i++) //print out message
      {
         for(j = 0; j < message[i].length; j++)
            {
            System.out.print(message[i][j]);
            }
         System.out.println();
      }
      System.out.println();
      for(i = 0; i< key.length; i++) //print out key
      {
         for(j = 0; j < key[i].length; j++)
            {
            System.out.print(key[i][j]);
            }
         System.out.println();
      }
      System.out.println();
      for(i = 0; i< overlay.length; i++) //print out overlay
      {
         for(j = 0; j < overlay[i].length; j++)
            {
            System.out.print(overlay[i][j]);
            }
         System.out.println();
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, take a look at your parameter sequence in `overlay()`:

```
public static char[][] overlay(int row, int i, int j,
    char[][] message, char[][] key, char[][] overlay)
```

And now here's how you're calling it in `main()`:

```
overlay = overlay(row, i, j, key, message, overlay);
```

See, you're passing `key, message, overlay` when the method wants `message, key, overlay`.

Then, in your `overlay()` method, it looks like you would want to change the logic inside the loop to this:

```
if (key[i][j] == 'x')
    overlay[i][j] = message[i][j];
else
    overlay[i][j] = ' ';
```

as well as return the `overlay` instead of the `message`:

```
return overlay;
```

**Alternate Implementation**

For educational purposes, here's a simplified version of your class using `ArrayList<String>` instead of `char[][]`:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Scratch
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<String> message = read("secret_message.txt");
        print(message);
        List<String> key = read("key.txt");
        print(key);
        List<String> overlay = overlay(message, key);
        print(overlay);
    }

    public static List<String> read(String filePath) throws IOException {
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        File f = new File(filePath);
        try (Scanner inFile = new Scanner(f)) {
            while (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
                lines.add(inFile.nextLine());
            }
        }
        return lines;
    }

    public static List<String> overlay(List<String> msg, List<String> key) {
        List<String> overlay = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < msg.size() && i < key.size(); i++) {
            StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
            for (int j = 0; j < msg.get(i).length() && j < key.get(i).length(); j++) {
                line.append(key.get(i).charAt(j) == 'x' ? msg.get(i).charAt(j)
                        : ' ');
            }
            overlay.add(line.toString());
        }
        return overlay;
    }

    public static void print(List<String> lines) {
        for (String line : lines) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does order matter when it comes to writing and calling a method? Your alternative implication was very informative and I'll look further into that, but my professor wants the class to use a 2D array to demonstrate our understanding of the concept. I tried your suggested edits, but when I ran my program. It still is unable to pull out the secret characters. I'm getting a copy of my original message file.

Comment: The method parameter order doesn't matter so much - but it does matter when you pass the parameters in the wrong sequence. You also need to `return overlay` from your `overlay()` method, instead of returning `message`.

Comment: Rewriting the if statement to..  if(key[i][j] != ' ')      ...message[i][j] = key[i][j];    it would overlay my message with the key file but where there should be letters in the space, their's just a blank. I don't understand the logic behind why the program is doing that.

Comment: I think you meant to say `if(key[i][j] != 'x') message[i][j] = ' ';`